# JS Plumb connect function not accepting params

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsplumb

```
instance.connect({
  source: "src",
  target: "tar",
  endpoint: ["Dot", {
    radius: 5,
    cssClass: "hasInfluencedEndpointStrong"
  }],
  anchor: "Center",
  paintStyle: {
    width: 25,
    height: 21,
    fill: "transparent"
  },
  scope: "hasInfluencedStrong",
  isSource: true,
  reattach: true,
  maxConnections: -1,
  connectorStyle: {
    stroke: "#708088",
    strokeWidth: 2.6,
    outlineStroke: "transparent",
    outlineWidth: 4
  },
  connectorOverlays: [
    ["Arrow", {
      location: -15.5,
      id: "arrow",
      length: 14,
      width: 14,
      foldback: 1,
      direction: 1
    }]
  ],
  isTarget: true,
})
```

**I have passed this object in jsplumb connect function its not behaving the way it is expected to i want to adjust the width of line and arrow type is there any alternative for this ?**

**UPDATE :**
i have tried to connect using uuid of endpoints also firstly the uuid of endpoints are added after that trying to connect them and consoled both uuid and the endpoint its same uuid but still getting source does not exist error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yl1NC.png)

Comment: Is `maxConnections: -1` on purpose? It seems like it can prevent nodes from accepting connections.

Comment: yes, it is on purpose as it allows unlimited connections

Answer (score 0):

it worked this way for me

```
let e1 = instance.addEndpoint("src", {
  endpoint: ["Dot", { radius: 5,  cssClass:"hasInfluencedEndpointStrong" }], 
  anchor: "Center", 
  paintStyle: { 
    width: 25, 
    height: 21, 
    fill:"transparent"
  }, 
  scope: "hasInfluencedStrong", 
  isSource: true, 
  reattach: true,
  maxConnections: -1, 
  connectorStyle: { 
    stroke: "#708088", 
    strokeWidth: 2.6, 
    outlineStroke: "transparent", 
    outlineWidth: 4 
  }, 
  connectorOverlays:[ 
    [ "Arrow", { location: -15.5, id: "arrow", length: 14, width:14, foldback: 1, direction:1 } ] 
  ]
});

let e2 = instance.addEndpoint("target", {
  endpoint: ["Dot", { radius: 5,  cssClass:"hasInfluencedEndpointStrong" }], 
  anchor: "Center", 
  paintStyle: { 
    width: 25, 
    height: 21, 
    fill:"transparent"
  }, 
  scope: "hasInfluencedStrong", 
  isTarget: true, 
  reattach: true,
  maxConnections: -1, 
  connectorStyle: { 
    stroke: "#708088", 
    strokeWidth: 2.6, 
    outlineStroke: "transparent", 
    outlineWidth: 4 
  }, 
  connectorOverlays:[ 
    [ "Arrow", { location: -15.5, id: "arrow", length: 14, width:14, foldback: 1, direction:1 } ] 
  ]
});
```

and then connect those endpoints:

```
instance.connect({
  source:e1,
  target:e2
});
```